# Should I use "inside the drawer" or "in the drawer" when I am talking about a small object?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, politeness, reading

When I was taking my English classes I came across a doubt: What's the proper way to say: I forgot my book **in** the drawer or **inside** the drawer?

Comment: I would normally say "I **left** my book **in** the drawer."

Comment: There is no proper way. They are both understandable and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best to use "in" or "out" when simply discussing location:

- The cup is in the cupboard.
- I left my book in the drawer.
- This dish is out of the dishwasher.

You would choose "inside" or "outside" when there's a reason to emphasize the *difference* between inside and outside:

- Clean the inside of the cup, not just the outside.
- I left the book inside the desk [to make sure your listener understands not just to look on top of the desk]
- Go play outside [of the house or building]